# Defining function in Python whose one argument is list

Tags: python, definition

There is a part of mathematics called the theory of multiple zeta values (MZVs) introduced around 1992. In this theory, we study the properties of parametric nested infinite series (see, e.g., [here](https://www.usna.edu/Users/math/meh/mult.html) for the definition of one particular variant) whose numeric evaluation is, therefore, of high computational complexity. Several days ago, I started using Python to calculate the basic partial sums of specific MZVs.

The following code allows me to calculate the 20th partial sum of the so-called multiple zeta-star value zeta*(10,2,1,1,1) or any other similar instance by changing the inputs `S`, `n`.

```
S = (10, 2, 1, 1, 1)
n = 20

l = len(S)

def F(d, N):
  if d == 0:
    return 1
  else:
    return sum(F(d-1, k)/(k**S[-d]) for k in range(1, N+1))

print(F(l, n))
```

Of course, the partial sums of the d-dimensional MZVs essentially depend on their arguments forming a d-tuple (s_1, ..., s_d) and on the upper summation bound `n`.

**My question** is whether we can define a function typed in a user-friendly way `F([s_1, ..., s_d], n)` with the first argument being a list with integer entries and the second argument being the summation bound n. Thus, instead of typing the two inputs separately, `S` and `n`, I am looking for a way to directly type `F([10, 2, 1, 1, 1], 20)` or `F([2, 1], 100)`, etc., with the given delimiters of the two arguments.

Comment: I'm not a maths person so maybe I'm just not grasping the issue, but... why can't you use e.g. `F([10,2,1,1,1],20)` and `F([2,1],100)` like you said?  What is the actual difficulty?

Comment: Would be `F(len([10,2,1,1,1]),20)` in this case

Comment: In your code, `S` is a global variable. I'm confused about the "instead of typing the two inputs separately, S and n," part. `S` isn't a parameter for the function. So either its not an input to your function, or your function has 3 inputs, depending on how you clasify use of global variables.

Comment: @CoderMuffin I think you misunderstood the question. OP wants "the first argument [to be] a list"

Comment: @wjandrea - I think that's part of the confusion. A list of what? The code calculates values on the global `S`. Why pass in a `d` as a list of values to be ignored?

Comment: Please update your question with the function that you want, (including how to call the function), but maybe with it not working since you don't know how to do that yet.

Comment: Thank you for your comments, but I am not able to follow them too much as Python is an entirely new world for me. I hope I haven't upset you too much. Maybe I'll find the courage to ask next time.
:)

Comment: You haven't upset us at all.  We're usually happy to help -- assuming we actually understand what is being asked, which in this case most of us didn't.

Comment: @JohnGordon apologies, my bad :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are looking for a function wrapper, which takes the arguments as you really want them, and which has the function `F` as a local function inside of it, and calls it:

```
def zeta(S, n):  # wrapper around F

    def F(d, n):
        if d == 0:
            return 1
        return sum(F(d-1, k)/(k**S[-d]) for k in range(1, n+1))

    return F(len(S), n)  # Call F and return what it returns

# Example call
result = zeta((10, 2, 1, 1, 1), 20)
print(result)
```